Is there a way in Unity3d in Visual Studio using C# to avoid from the options to cover the document of a method?
When I type ( to see what parameters the method can take, I should get the options get over it and hide it.
The problem is when I click the arrows up/down to see more options and then the options I marked in red in second screenshot get over it like in the first screenshot so you can't see what the method should get.

This is an example of what I mean: the options that the method can/should get:

This is marked with red what I mean. Now I can see clear what things the Instantiate should and can get. But when I click the arrows up/down then the options i marked in red too get over it like in the first

For me in VS2022 17.11.4, they are not overlapping. Deleted the ( and rewrote it to get that overload helper including the suggestions box but the top entry in the suggestion box is also the top entry if I only conjure the suggestion box on its own (ctrl+space). So in the former, they spawn next to each other. Sounds like a bug. What version are you on?

You can just use the Ctrl+Shift+Space to just conjure the overloads/parameter list box and the keys are now only bound on that UI. You won't get the member/type list thing (which you can use on its own with Ctrl+Space). Btw when I first do Ctrl+Shift+Space and then Ctrl+Space, both are open but again, not overlapping. Do they overlap for you?

After typing (, you only need to type characters like /,] to make the things that cover you disappear.
The phenomenon you encounter:

The effect after typing characters(You can use the up and down keys to switch and view different definitions):


Hi @Daniel Lip ,I would like to ask if this method can meet your needs.
